# Recursion in JavaScript - not recursing

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to get a recursion work in JavaScript. This is my code.

```
var getCategory = null;
getCategory = function (id, cats) {
    if (!cats || !cats.length) return null;

    for (var i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
        var cat = cats[i];

        if (cat && cat.Id == id) {
            return cat;
        }
        else if (cat && cat.Children && cat.Children.length) {
            return getCategory(id, cat.Children);
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code basically searches in the hierarchy of data for a specific element of a specific id.

Let's say that my sample data is:

```
 var sampleData = [
   {Id : 1, Children : [{Id:11, Children:[]}, {Id : 12, Children : []}]},
   {Id : 2, Children : [{Id:21, Children:[]}, {Id : 22, Children : []}, {Id : 23, Children : []}]},
   {Id : 3, Children : [{Id:31, Children:[]}, {Id : 32, Children : []}, {Id : 33, Children : []}]}
 ]
```

The problem is that when I call this function like:

```
getCategoriy(21, sampleData); //it gives null
```

even when get:

```
getCategiry(11, sampleData); //gives perfect object back
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use a debugger. If you used a debugger (there's one built into your browser), and stepped through the code, you'd see quite quickly what was going wrong.

Comment: wow a downvote to an answered question that was asked 2 years back. without a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're starting to loop through the `cats`, but if you see an entry that has children, you're recursing into that entry and then terminating your loop. That means you don't see any of the `cats` *after* that entry.

Instead of

```
return getCategory(id, cat.Children);
```

You need to call it and only return *if* it returns `!null`:

```
value = getCategory(id, cat.Children);
if (value) {
    return value;
}
```